# Fastest way to write a post and auto sync it with 1000 sites

Tags: php, wordpress, synchronization, auto

I'm writing WordPress plugin which can post to many sites at once. When I publish a post or create a user or category on server, all content will be sync with clients by using form post method. But the code run too slowly.

How can I speed up synchronization of data?

Comment: Posting data to 1000 sites once should be very slow (even 3 sites will be very slow). You should run that into a cronjob or something.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to go would to create a plugin that hooks into the [save_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) action. This will be triggered when a post is saved (added or modified). Then store the post ID in a custom queue table. Using a cronjob script you can work the queue every x minutes and post the data through xmlrpc to the other websites.